# problems with replacing first line of file using perl

Tags: perl, io

I have a file that looks like this:

```
I,like
blah...
```

I want to replace only the first line with 'i,am' to get:

```
i,am
blah...
```

These are big files, so this is what I did ([based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548420/how-can-i-make-changes-to-only-the-first-line-of-a-file)):

```
open(FH, "+< input.txt") or die "FAIL!";
my $header = <FH>;
chop($header);
$header =~ s/I,like/i,am/g;
seek FH, 0, 0; # go back to start of file
printf FH $header;
close FH;
```

However, I get this when I run it:

```
i,amke
blah...
```

I looks like the 'ke' from like is still there.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Just think about it for a while. File is set of bytes. You replaced *some* of them. The rest is the same. You can't "remove" bytes from the middle without having to move all other bytes.

Comment: What you want to do is like deleting from the middle of an array - you need to shift all the remaining elements to the left.

Comment: Can I 'delete' the first line, and insert the new one?  If so, how would I do that?

Comment: @jh314 i think your confusion is coming from the fact that a file has no concept of lines, only bytes. An end of line token is just another byte. Imagine if the file is a big array of characters. How would you do it then?

Answer (score 7):

What I would do is probably something like this:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ($. == 1) { s/.*/i,am/; }' yourfile.txt
```

Which will only affect the first line, when the line counter for the current file handle `$.` is equal to 1. The regex will replace everything except newline. If you need it to match your specific line, you can include that in the if-statement:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ($. == 1 and /^I,like$/) { s/.*/i,am/; }' yourfile.txt
```

You can also look into [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File), which allows you to treat the file like an array, which means you can simply do `$line[0] = "i,am\n"`. It is mentioned that there may be performance issues with this module, however.

Comment: Tie::File would make this trivial and possibly a great solution here, but note that you can always crank out code that's faster and uses less memory than Tie::File.

Comment: I'm trying to do this as a subroutine of a large perl program, which in turn is called by other programs.  Will this still work?

Comment: Yes and no. The equivalent would be something like: `{ local $^I = ''; local @ARGV = 'input.txt'; while (<>) { s/// if $. == 1; print; } }`

Answer (score 3):

If the replacement has a different length than the original, you cannot use this technique. You can for example create a new file and then rename it to the original name.

```
open my $IN,  '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', 'input.new' or die $!;
my $header = <$IN>;
$header =~ s/I,like/i,am/g;
print $OUT $header;
print $OUT $_ while <$IN>;               # Just copy the rest.

close $IN;
close $OUT or die $!;
rename 'input.new', 'input.txt' or die $!;
```

Comment: I'd quibble with 'have to'. He can overwrite the orginal if he just buffers the entire operation in memory.

Comment: @frankc, Actually, can also be done without reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @ikegami, yes i agree with that. I was just pointing out that 'have to' was a bit strong and providing a counter-example. I think the choroba's answer is fine overall, though i might prefer the sed style command line way myself.

Comment: @frankc, I agree. I only commented on your second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use Tie::File;

sub firstline {
  tie my @f, 'Tie::File', shift or die $!;
  $f[0] = shift;
  untie @f;
}

firstline $0, '#! ' . qx(which perl);
```

Usage:

```
$ ./example
$ head -2 example
#! /bin/perl
use common::sense;
```