# Does this piece of Perl code do what it says?

Tags: perl

While searching for something, I came across this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548434/4502993).

I want to know why the variable `$first_line` contains only the first line of the input file.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $filename = shift;
open my $in_fh, '<', $filename
  or die "Cannot open $filename for reading: $!";
my $first_line = <$in_fh>;

open my $out_fh, '>', "$filename.tmp"
  or die "Cannot open $filename.tmp for writing: $!";

$first_line =~ s/some translation/goes here/;

print {$out_fh} $first_line;
print {$out_fh} $_ while <$in_fh>; # sysread/syswrite is probably better

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;

# overwrite original with modified copy
rename "$filename.tmp", $filename
  or warn "Failed to move $filename.tmp to $filename: $!";
```

As I understand, the entire content of `$in_fh` is stored in `$first_line`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `<FH>` will either return the first line of the file when it is used in a scalar context, or the complete contents of the file if used in list context:

```
my $first_line = <FH>;
my @lines = <FH>;
```

The reason for this is that, by default, the built-in input record separator (`$/`) is defined as newline. If you would redefine or undefine the record separator, you could slurp the entire file into a scalar variable:

```
undef $/;
my $lines = <FH>;
```

However, beware of the risks of globally redefining Perl built-in variables. You could use `local` to apply it only to the current scope.

```
local $/;
my $lines = <FH>;
```

A [post on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647) suggests this idiom to limit the scope of undefining `$/`:

```
my $lines = do { local $/; <FH> };
```

Answer (score 4):

In the code, `my $first_line` is scalar context.  In scalar context, the `<$in_fh>` reads and returns a single line.

In array context, `<$in_fh>` would read all lines (or run out of memory):

```
my @all_lines = <$in_fh>;
```

Context is a very important concept in Perl — and a subtle concept, too.